# How to render XML document to iframe?

Tags: jquery, xml, servlets, iframe, xml-parsing

My objective is to allow the user to input a value, obtain some XML corresponding to said value, and render the obtained XML within an iframe.

I have the following jQuery code in my HTML file:

```
$.post('VerifyServlet', { action: "getDocument", "tcNo": tcNo, "pgNo": pgNo }, function(data) {
    var xml = "<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"../xsl/esigtest.xsl\"?>" + data;
    var ifrm = document.getElementById('xmlLoader');
    ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
    ifrm.document.open('text/xml');
    ifrm.document.write(xml);
    ifrm.document.close();
    });
```

The relevant code in my servlet is as follows:

```
response.setContentType("text/xml");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println(xmlString);
```

Then I have my iframe...

```
...
<td colspan="3">
    <iframe id="xmlLoader" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</td>
...
```

Put together, the result shown in my iframe is

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../xsl/esigtest.xsl"?>[object XMLDocument]
```

I infer that `[object XMLDocument]` is probably referring to `data`, and that the `toString` method of XMLDocument is being invoked. However, what I actually want is to have the XML rendered using the XSL stylesheet and the results displayed.

I honestly have no idea how to go about this, so I tried permutations of the MIME type, between `text/plain`, `text/xml`, `application/xml`, but nothing works. Is there a way to do what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

To make an xml you can use this sintax

```
 var xml = $('<xml>', { version : "1.0", encoding : "UTF-8" });
```

the first parameter is the name of the node, the second is an object whose proerties will became the attributes of the node.

then you can use jQuery methods to create the xml

```
var head = $('<head>');
head.appendTo(xml);
```